# Update not yielding correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

```
UPDATE @DList1
SET
Listed = a.Listed +  b.Listed,
Sold = b.Sold,
Volume = a.Volume + ISNULL(b.Volume, 0)
FROM @DList1 a, @DList2 b 
WHERE a.ItemID = b.ItemID
```

In the above updated statement  the column `[Listed]` is not getting updated correctly where as `[Volume]` does.

**Dlist2**

```
ItemID  Listed  Sold Volume
104     NULL    1    266000
778     1       1    5390
200     1       0    266000
```

**Dlist1**

```
ItemID  Listed  Sold Volume
200     1       0    6395000
779     1       0    155000
```

**After the update @Dlist1**

```
ItemID  Listed  Sold Volume
200     1       0    6661000
779     1       0    155000
```

**Scheme:**

```
DECLARE @DList1 TABLE 
( 
    ItemID          NVARCHAR(20)
    , Listed        BIGINT
    , Sold          BIGINT
    , Volume        BIGINT
)

DECLARE @DList2 TABLE 
( 
      ItemID        NVARCHAR(20)
    , Listed        BIGINT
    , Sold          BIGINT
    , Volume        BIGINT
)
```

Comment: Don't use the a,b join syntax

Comment: Can you post the table structure for both tables? Then we can see the datatype.

Comment: the datatype on listed is  BIGINT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the first line to `UPDATE a`. This way, you're telling SQL that the records you want updated are the ones in `DList1` that have a match in `DList2` by `ItemID` (you're updating the same `DList1` that you are referring to below).

Also, use join syntax instead of `from a,b where...` because it leads to queries that are much more readable and maintainable:

```
UPDATE a
SET
  Listed = a.Listed +  b.Listed,
  Sold = b.Sold,
  Volume = a.Volume + ISNULL(b.Volume, 0)
FROM @DList1 a
JOIN @DList2 b 
  on a.ItemID = b.ItemID;
```

Here's an SQLFiddle link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8cfc/3

Comment: @abatishchev Right. Corrected.

Comment: @BumbleBee it may be because I dropped the `@` in the table names (I used regular tables instead of table variables)

Comment: @BumbleBee the join here works for me. I suspect you did something wrong in translation.

Comment: @BumbleBee take a look at the SqlFiddle link. After the update, the row where `ItemID = 200` has the value `2` in the `Listed` column. Therefore, the update executed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Join two tables and update and make sure to use `isnull()` or `coalesce()` if you are *`adding/concatenating`* with *`nullable fields`*;

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.Listed = isnull(a.Listed, b.Listed),
    a.Sold = b.Sold,
    a.Volume = a.Volume + isnull(b.Volume, 0)
FROM @DList1 a join @DList2 b  on a.ItemID = b.ItemID
```

### [SQL-FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5fe0/5)

Comment: I have added a fiddle demo to the answer, it does work. Also made it `a.Listed = isnull(a.Listed, b.Listed)` to get expected results as shown.